# PHP get value of array by position

Tags: php

I am pulling the latest 3 news articles from my database and I need to access them by the order they were pulled from, so first position in the array, second position and so on to display them in order in random sections of my web page. I came across accessing the array key but that is not working, where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
$value = array_slice($blog, 0, 1);
echo $value;
```

Comment: `$blog[0]`, `$blog[1]`, ...? Or what are you asking exactly?

Comment: `echo $blog[0]; echo $blog[1]; echo $blog[2]` should work ?

Comment: u should loop through the array.. dont slice

Comment: what error its showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop or something like that:

```php
$blog = array('foo', 'bar', 'cat');
foreach ($blog as $article) {
    echo $article;
}
/**
 * Gives you:
 *
       foo
       bar
       cat
 */
```

---

But if you want to do it with functions, you can use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array-shift). This will remove the first element from an array and return that:

```php
$article1 = array_shift($blog); // $blog is now `array('bar', 'cat')`
echo $article1; // >> foo

$article2 = array_shift($blog); // $blog is now `array('cat')`
echo $article2; // >> bar

$article3 = array_shift($blog); // $blog is now `array()`
echo $article2; // >> cat
```

---

Or if you want to keep the original `$blog` array, use array pointer functions like [`current`](http://php.net/current), [`next`](http://php.net/next), [`prev`](http://php.net/prev), [`reset`](http://php.net/reset) and [`end`](http://php.net/end):

```php
reset($blog);
$article1 = current($blog); // >> foo
$article2 = next($blog); // >> bar
$article3 = next($blog); // >> cat
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$value = array_shift($blog);
```

To get second one

```
$value2 = array_shift($blog);
```

and third :

```
$value3 = array_shift($blog);
```

Comment: and in case you want to keep the old $blog array untouched use `$value = array_shift(array_values($blog));`

Comment: I don't think this is working? `$value` and `$value2` are both strings, so calling `array_shift` on them will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have three different ways to accomplish this:

**1. Call array_shift($blog) each time you want to get the next value.**

```
   $value = array_shift($blog);
```

Each time you do the array_shift it will return the next entry in the array.

Function array_pop is similar but returns the last entry in the array each time.

**2. Simply access each entry of the array using the index**

This gives the first entry in the array:

```
    $value = $blog[0]
```

This gives the second entry in the array:

```
    $value = $blog[1]
```

This gives the n'th value in the array:

```
    $value = $blog[n-1];
```

**3. Or finally you can simply loop through the array and echo out each entry (may not be suitable if you don't want to sequentially echo out the entries in the same place)**

```
foreach ($blog as $blog_entry) {
    echo $blog_entry;
}
```